# How to display a list of records with value event in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to create a blog. And I am referring to firebase documentation for the same purpose.
I am wondering how to retrieve a list of records from the database using value event...!
Can someone explain me the difference between value event and child_added event?

[image]

Comment: can you provide your firebase database screenshot

Comment: @ashish check the image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPWxb.png

Comment: Do you want to retrieve data from firebase right?

Comment: exact this........... but i want to retrieve list with value event !!!

Comment: please check my answer below

Comment: @PravinSingh here was an answer I was trying to type before you deleted your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974962/how-to-display-elements-of-array-with-javascript): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5m20j1k/2/)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts
Thank you so much..... you are an exception .... !!

Answer (score 2):

> You can retrieve your data using below code. Here just console the data after that you can access what ever like. So here just get data. Like below :

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
```

1) 'Value' event will be triggered every time the data changes and it will retrieve all data including children

2) child_added
This event type will be triggered once for every 'blog' and every time new 'blog' is added to our data. It is useful for reading list data because we get access of the added player and previous player from the list.

**For Nested child try with below code**

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(messageSnapshot) {
    console.log(messageSnapshot.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: but if child has nested children the response is null

Comment: console.log(snapshot.child("more child").val());
but if child has nested children the response is null

Comment: Now please check again